# exponential distribution?

Tags: self-study, simulation

given a Poisson process with 
lambda = 1.4 for 0<=t<2
and
lambda = 0.6 for 2<=t<10
if we only focus on the first arrival, what is the distribution of arrival time (X1)? is it still exponential? and is it possible to express the cdf in terms of a closed form function so that we can use the inverse cdf method to simulate it?

Answer (score 0):

We compute for $0\leqslant t<10$
$$
\mathbb P(X_1\leqslant t, X_1< 2) = \int_0^{t\wedge 2} \frac75 e^{-\frac75 s}\ \mathsf ds = 1 - e^{-\frac75 (t\wedge 2)}
$$
where $\wedge$ denotes $\min$, and
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X_1\leqslant t, X_1\geqslant 2) &= \mathbb P(X_1\leqslant t\mid X_1\geqslant 2)\mathbb P(X_1\geqslant 2)\\
&= \left(\int_2^t \frac35 e^{-\frac35 s}\ \mathsf ds\right)e^{-\frac{14}5}\\
&= e^{-4} - e^{-\frac15(14-3t)}.
\end{align}
It follows that for $0\leqslant t<10$,
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X_1\leqslant t) &= \mathbb P(X_1\leqslant t, X_1< 2) + \mathbb P(X_1\leqslant t, X_1\geqslant 2)\\
&= 1 - e^{-\frac75 (t\wedge 2)} + e^{-4} - e^{-\frac15(14+3t)}
\end{align}
Since the arrival rate is zero after $t=10$, we have 
$$
\mathbb P(X_1=+\infty) = 1 - \mathbb P(X_1\leqslant 10) = e^{-\frac{14}5} - e^{-4} + e^{-\frac{44}5}.
$$